# Execute Cython function in PHP via FFI

Tags: python, php, c, cython, ffi

So this is firmly in mad scientist territory, but I need to use the [`wordnet`](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) utility from the Python NLTK package in a PHP application.
I cannot shell out to a Python process for performance reasons -- this specific part of the code is going to get called a lot. I also cannot realistically port the code to PHP without serious effort, and there is no comparable library available.

Therefore, I'm trying to compile a wrapper function (1) exposing the wordnet reader to a shared C library using [Cython](https://cython.org)(2), which I can load in PHP using its [FFI](https://cython.org) interface(3). In theory, this should make it possible to invoke the Python function directly from PHP code.
The code compiles fine, but I stumble over dependency errors when invoking the library:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught FFI\ParserException: Undefined C type "PyObject" at line 2 in /build/test.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /build/test.php(5): FFI::cdef()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /build/test.php on line 5
```

How can I fix this?

---

1. The wrapper script `wordnet.pyx`:

   ```py
   from nltk.corpus import wordnet

   def synonyms(word: str) -> list[str]:
       return wordnet.synonyms(word)
   ```
2. The `setup.py` file:

   ```py
   from distutils.core import setup
   from Cython.Build import cythonize

   setup(
       ext_modules=cythonize(
           'wordnet.pyx',
           compiler_directives={'language_level': '3'}
       )
   )
   ```

   The C header file `wordnet.h`:

   ```c
   #include <Python.h>
   PyObject* wordnet(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
   ```
3. The PHP test script:

   ```php
   <?php
   $ffi = FFI::cdef(
        file_get_contents("/build/wordnet.h"),
        "/build/wordnet_wrapper.so"
   );

   $result = $ffi->wordnet("dog");
   ```

The compilation steps:

```bash
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
gcc -Wall \
    -pthread \
    -fwrapv \
    -O2 \
    -fPIC \
    -fno-strict-aliasing \
    -shared -o wordnet_wrapper.so \
    wordnet.c \
    -I /usr/local/include/python3.11 \
    -L /usr/local/lib/python3.11 \
    -L /usr/local/lib \
    -lpython3.11
```

Comment: Instead of this, why not Python via FCGI and make it an internal microservice?

Comment: We're planning to use this system in autocompletion for a search input, and I want to keep latency as low as possible. This specific synonym function is going to see >= several hundred requests per second. But sure, if the FFI way won't work, that's the road I'm going down.

Comment: That's not a lot for Python to serve as a persistent process, or as a pool of processes as it's often configured. You can set it up as a gRPC service which usually responds very quickly. It's likely a lot more reliable than banging around with FFI and loading Python into PHP. Unless you keep that Python engine running, you'll end up reloading the Python code every request, way slower than FCGI.